# Check If a number is contained in an interval without using "if" or loops

Tags: java

So, I have a basic question. I could solve this easily but I am dumbfounded at the moment because my teacher would like us to solve this not using any if statements or loops. So the interval is not an array. A basic example is [1,6] or (1,6) or a mixed of both open and closed. So, 5 would be in the interval. I need a contains(double number) method that checks if the number is inside. How can you possibly do this without an if or loop? Am I stupid? Is there some magic method that I have not stumbled upon that does this?

My approach would be something along the lines of

```
public double contains(number)
{
    if (number >= leftEndPoint && number <= rightEndPoint) //lets assume interval is "closed" heh. on both ends
    return true;

    return false;

}
```

But...We can't use an if statement or loop.

Comment: "lets assume interval is open" actually your example is a closed interval.

Comment: heh oops :D @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the expression in the condition of an `if` statement evaluates to either `true` or `false`. This means you can return the value directly rather than having an explicit `if`.  In general,

```
if (x)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

can be replaced by

```
return x;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to return a boolean value of true or false. Every conditional expression returns such a value, which you can return in your function without having if-statements:

```
public boolean contains(double number) {
    return number >= startNum && number <= endNum;
}
```

That works perfectly fine if you - of course - define the `startNum` and `endNum` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(x)
    return true;
```

never makes sense. At least, it never makes more sense than `if (true) /* something */;` or `if (isOn == true) /**/`.

Please write:

```
return number >= leftEndPoint && number <= rightEndPoint;
```

and thank you.

Comment: Okay but assume the interval is open. That only solves it if its closed.

Comment: @CalebBishop can you please figure it out from here, thanks

Comment: @CalebBishop In Java code, what is the difference between an open and a closed interval?

Comment: In java code? In math. open is a < x < b. closed is a <= x <= b. Where as a and b are the lower and upper bounds. I get them mixed up every now and then though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Pretty verbose, but should be maintainable.

```
public class Interval {
  final int bottom;
  final int top;
  final IntervalEvaluationStrategy strategy;

  public Interval(final int bottom, final int top, final IntervalEvaluationStrategy strategy) {
    this.bottom = bottom;
    this.top = top;
    this.strategy = strategy;
  }

  public boolean check(int value) {
    return strategy.evaluate(value, bottom, top);
  }

  public enum IntervalEvaluationStrategy {
    OPEN {
      @Override
      boolean evaluate(int value, int bottom, int top) {
        return CLOSED.evaluate(value, bottom, top)
            || value == bottom
            || value == top;
      }
    },
    CLOSED {
      @Override
      boolean evaluate(int value, int bottom, int top) {
        return value > bottom
            && value < top;
      }
    };

    abstract boolean evaluate(int value, int bottom, int top);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    assert checkInterval(5, 5, 10, IntervalEvaluationStrategy.OPEN);
  }

  //helper method with example usage
  public static boolean checkInterval(final int value, final int bottom, final int top, IntervalEvaluationStrategy strategy) {
    final Interval interval = new Interval(bottom, top, strategy);
    return interval.check(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Conditional operator can also be used.
For example:
return (number >= leftEndPoint && number <= rightEndPoint)?true:false;

Comment: Your `Conditional operator` is actually a `ternary operator`, and using it is overkill.

Comment: Since the value of the condition is already either `true` or `false`, why waste the time with the extra typing?